# Unable to access sudo in Ubuntu virtual machine

Tags: permissions, sudo

I installed Ubuntu 22.10 desktop version on Oracle Vmware. I am unable to use the sudo command since I am not in the sudoers list. Solutions on the internet suggest entering the root mode using `su` command however I am unable to access root as well. All the other solutions need root access or being a sudo user. How should get into the sudoers list without either being a root user or having sudo access with another username.

Kindly help since I am stuck in this loop.

Comment: If you are the person who installed Ubuntu in a VM, then the account you specified at the time of installation should be able to use `sudo` unless: (1) you're using a different account that was created later (2) you removed `sudo` permissions from the first account 

Comment: @matigo Hello, I am not using a different account. I am using the same account but surprisingly I do not have sudo access. Also, I have no idea how to remove sudo permissions from my account since I am new to Linux.

Comment: In a terminal, type `groups <your login ID>`.  What does it say?  Is `sudo` one of the groups listed?

Comment: "*I am unable to use the sudo command since I am not in the sudoers list.*" The normal installer adds your account to the sudoers list automatically. Did you install Ubuntu some strange way? Or did you download some pre-installed VM image?

Comment: @karel Thanks I resolved my issue using that link.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1: Boot your Linux system into recovery mode.**

To do so, **restart your system and press and hold the SHIFT key while booting**. **You will see the grub boot menu. Choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" from the boot menu list**.
In the next screen, choose **"recovery mode**" option and **hit ENTER**.
Next, choose **"Drop to root shell prompt"** option and hit ENTER key.

You're now in recovery mode as root user.

**Step 2: Mount root file system in read/write mode. To do so, type the following command to mount root (/) file system in read/write mode.**

**$ mount -o remount,rw /**

**Step 3: Now, add the user that you removed from the sudo group.**

In my case, I am adding the user called **'john'** to the sudo group using the following command:

**$ adduser john sudo**

**Step 4: Then, type exit to return back to the recovery menu. Select Resume to start your Ubuntu system.**

Press ENTER to continue to log-in normal mode.

**Step 5: Now check if the sudo privileges have been restored.**

**$ sudo -l -U sk**

Comment: Thanks, I entered the recovery mode and edited the \etc\sudoers list and added myself in the sudoers list.